# Adding animations to routed components on routing events

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to get it so when the user switches tabs, it will slide between them.

I am using animate.css and version 4 of Angular2.

I detect the router change and add the animation like this:

```
    this.router.events.pairwise().filter((e) => e[0] instanceof NavigationEnd && e[1] instanceof NavigationStart).subscribe((e: [NavigationStart, NavigationEnd]) => {
            $("#home").addClass("animated slideOutRight").one("animationend", function() {
                $(this).removeClass("animated slideOutRight");
            })
            $("#about").addClass("animated slideInLeft").one("animationend", function() {
                $(this).removeClass("animated slideInLeft");
            })
    });
```

where `#home` and `#about` are the components being routed to. Those two ids are placed to cover HomeComponent and AboutComponent.

```
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
```

The animation works when using something that isn't in the `<router-outlet>` (eg when using `$("body")`) so I'm guessing I need to do something differently about the router components.